# Label Text in Kivy Blurry

Tags: python, kivy, label, kivy-language, kivymd

My simple label in kivy is very blurry, I just wanted to know how to make it look sharper?
Here's the code:

[image]
[image]

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be coming from you. On Windows 10, click the `windows button`/`search`, type `ClearType`. One of the options should say `Adjust ClearType Text`. Open that, and follow the wizard